# Change the date to UNIX timestamp in all stock quotes for highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to make graph of stock quotes (downloaded from yahoo finance as csv and changed to json array), but date is in standard format(mm/dd/yyyy) but highstocks works only in unix timestamp (i guess). please give me the whole code on how to change the time's format. i know about date.parse() but i don't know how to apply this to whole data.
please help me with the code please

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?a=e&filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector: {
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                selected: 1
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: [ // Y: [Open, High ,Low, Close]
                    /* May 2006 */
                    [Date.parse("8/2/2012"), 602.84, 610.69, 600.25, 607.79, 83039600],
                    [Date.parse("8/3/2012"), 613.63, 617.98, 611.56, 615.7, 86230200],
                    [Date.parse("8/6/2012"), 617.29, 624.87, 615.26, 622.55, 75525800],
                    [Date.parse("8/7/2012"), 622.77, 625, 618.04, 620.91, 72611700]
                    ["8/7/2012", 622.77, 625, 618.04, 620.91, 72611700],
                    ["8/6/2012", 617.29, 624.87, 615.26, 622.55, 75525800],
                    ["8/3/2012", 613.63, 617.98, 611.56, 615.7, 86230200],
                    ["8/2/2012", 602.84, 610.69, 600.25, 607.79, 83039600],
                    ["8/1/2012", 615.91, 616.4, 603, 606.81, 96125400]
                ],
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: [
                        [
                            'week', // unit name
                            [1] // allowed multiples
                        ],
                        [
                            'month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

i'm inputting the data manually,still i don't know the use of sample data

```
 $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?a=e&filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=?', function (data) {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get data from json, you need to use map your dates to timestamps, in the preprocessing. Use any loop / condition to prepare new array with series, including correct values.